# My twilio account say - Voice is unavailable for this phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I live in Australia and I have a paid Twilio account.

Quoting the Twilio guide

```
Each phone number has two configurable webhooks:
  Voice Request URL for incoming phone calls
  Messaging Request URL for incoming SMS or MMS messages
```

I can only find a primary and secondary message handler. On my `Phone Numbers` page it says my capabilities are `Voice`, `SMS` and `MMS`. If I click on the `phone number` It opens an `Active Numbers` page that say `Voice is unavailable for this phone number.` What am I missing?

Comment: Was my answer incorrect? If it was please let me know. I spent some time investigating this and thought I could help another Australian with the same issue. There is an 'answer your own question option' you know. I had a look at your profile, 'Twilio evangelist'. Thanks for your help Marcos Placona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to have separate number for voice and SMS in Australia. You have to purchase one for voice and another for SMS.